Conditions for Convexity of a Product of Functions
I am studying the convexity of a product of functions and would like some assistance identifying additional conditions on one of the functions.
Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ $ be a non-decreasing convex function. Additionally, let $ g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0,1] $ be a function satisfying the following properties:

List item
$ g(z, x) = 0 $ if and only if $z = x $,
List item
$ g(z, x) $ is increasing in $ z $ for $ z > x $ and decreasing in $ z $ for $ z < x $, mirroring the monotonicity behavior of $ f(|z - x|) $.

Given these conditions, I am interested in ensuring the convexity of the function $ h(z, x) = f(|z - x|) g(z, x) $.
Since $ f(|z - x|) $ is convex, I understand that if $ g $ were convex, this would be sufficient to establish the convexity of $ h $. However, since $g $ is bounded, it cannot satisfy convexity on its own.
My question is: What additional conditions on $ g $ are required for the convexity of $ h(z, x) = f(|z - x|) g(z, x) $?
Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!
I would also like to allow for discontinuity on $g$, at least at $z=x$.
Thanks!!!

The "List item" that appears when you press the Bulleted List button is just placeholder text for what you want to list. You should delete it.

A constant function is non-decreasing and convex, so $f$ could be constant. Any positive multiple of a convex function is also convex. If $f$ is constant, then $g$ would be a constant multiple of $h$, so $h$ could only be convex if $g$ is. But as you've noted, $g$ cannot be convex. You need stronger conditions on $f$, not just $g$, to show that $h$ is convex.
